# CKEDITOR Real Time Edit Iframe - Jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, ckeditor

It's kind of long but, it has pictures! :D

The one that I'm working on is some sort of real live editing which consists of  **preview** and the **editor**

**How it works**

When I click one of the blocks that can be high lightened, the value of the block will be transferred to the **ckeditor**.

Here's the code that I'm working on.

I have this `external.php` which would be the contents of the `iframe`. I just chopped the code since the elements are all redundant.

```
<div class="container">

    <div id="block-1" class="row click">First Row</div>

    <div id="block-2" class="row click">Second Row</div>

    <div class="row">

        <div id="block-3" class="column click">
            First Column
        </div>

        <div id="block-4" class="column click">
            Second Column
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I have this `index.php` which contains the iframe and the ckeditor.

```
<div id="main">

    <div id="left-col" class="col">
        <iframe src="external.php" width="500" height="600"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="right-col" class="col">
        <textarea name="editor" id="editor" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

And for the fun part, here lies the code where it all happens

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor;

    $('iframe').load(function() {

        var iframe = $('iframe').contents();

        iframe.find(".click").on("click", function(){

            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var box_value = $(this).html();

            CKEDITOR.instances.editor.setData(box_value);

            editor.on('change', function () {
                var value = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData()
                iframe.find("#" + id).html(value);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Here's what it looks like

[image]

So when I click **First Row** the value will be transferred into the **ckeditor.**

[image]

As the time I'm typing, the values are automatically being transferred.

[image]

When I click other block and try to do some live editing, the recent block that I edited also overwrites on what I'm doing on the latest block.

[image]

[image]

Until it was all covered in nooo!-es.

[image]

Don't you worry! I have a lead!

It seems when I alert below the ckeditor onchange event and I click one of the blocks.

[image]

It alerts the corresponding id on the blocks that I've clicked.

[image]

Yet if I put alert inside the ckeditor onchange event and click some of the blocks and try to edit it. It alerted me all the blocks that I've clicked **(in order)**.

[image]

Meaning, **id** is somewhat being stored in ckeditor onchange event which I don't even know why.

Obviously, the problem is, when I click the block and tried to edit it, and I click **different** block and edit it, both blocks are being updated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the people who answered here.

I totally forgot about this one, well I've already finished it last week.

Here's what I've come up with.

**Note:** This is not all of my code, I just chopped that includes on this problem.

I created a counter for it.

```
var ctr = 0;
//Editor Name counter
var editor = "e_" + ctr;

// Do create text editor
$("#editor-container").prepend("<textarea id='"+ editor +"' name='"+ editor +"' data-num='"+ ctr +"' class='text-editor' rows='10' cols='80'></textarea>");

// Do re-create CKeditor instance
if (CKEDITOR.instances[editor]) {
    delete CKEDITOR.instances[editor];
} CKEDITOR.replace(editor);

// Do check existing textarea
if (ctr > 0) {

    // Do loop textarea
    $(".text-editor").each( function() {

        var text_editor = $(this);
        var text_editor_id = text_editor.attr("id");
        ctr_editor = parseInt(text_editor.attr("data-num")) - 1;

        // Do remove recent textarea
        if (ctr_editor < ctr && ctr_editor >= 0) {
            $("#e_" + ctr_editor + ", #cke_e_" + ctr_editor ).remove();
        }
    });
}

// Do get contents of div
var default_val = contents.find(".editable[name='"+ cb +"']").html();
CKEDITOR.instances[editor].setData(default_val);

CKEDITOR.instances[editor].on("change", function() {

    var value = CKEDITOR.instances[editor].getData();
    contents.find(".editable[name='"+ cb +"']").html(value);
})

// Do increment counter
ctr++;
```

So when the user saves the editor using save button

```
/* Close editor */
$("#save-editor").on("click", function() {
    $("#editor-wrapper").animate({ width: 0 });

    // Do update editor name counter
    editor = "e_" + ctr;
    cb = "cb" + ctr;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a new change event every time you click on a div. Add the change event once when the page loads. When you click on a div, set a global id variable that the change event can use.

Answer (score 0):

Like @NoGray suggested you can make id global and bin the editor.onchange once

```
 $('iframe').load(function () {

     var iframe = $('iframe').contents();

     var id = 'someDefault';

     iframe.find(".click").on("click", function () {

         id = $(this).attr("id");
         var box_value = $(this).html();

         CKEDITOR.instances.editor.setData(box_value);
     });
     editor.on('change', function () {
         var value = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData()
         iframe.find("#" + id).html(value);
     });
 });
```

when you click on a div id copies the html into the editor and set the id of that div. this id is read when the editor changes

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(e){
    $("body").click(function(){
        $(".cke").each(function(){
            var idd = $(this).attr("id");
            var namme = idd.substr(4);
            var content = $("#" + idd + " iframe").contents().find('body').html();
            $("textarea[name=" + namme + "]").val(content);
        });
    });
```

Comment: You need to expand your answer to explain what exactly you're responding to.